# CSS transition width and height from center of div

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have elements with **position: absolute;** that I want to transition in certain situations. However, the origin of the width and height transition seems to depend on the top/bottom left/right values.

**Is there any way to have more control over this?**

I am specifically looking to transition from the center of the div.

Is there any solution that doesn't rely on transitioning also the top/bottom left/right values?

---

**Edit**:

I want to keep the width and height transitioning.

Thank you for the answers but using **Transform scale is not a solution** in this case. Percentages in the [Transform property](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-2d-transforms-20111215/) refer to the size of the element's border box, not the container. See for example [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gyp3f7k/), how the end result of hovering over the two elements is different.

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36hhyvkg/)

```css
div, span {
  width:30%;
  height:30%;
  background:pink;
  transition:all 1s ease;
  position:absolute;
}
*:hover{
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
}
div{
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
}
span{
  bottom:10%;
  right:10%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Have you played around with various values for `transition-origin`? Like `transition-origin: 50% 50%;`?

Comment: [Just did](https://jsfiddle.net/36hhyvkg/1). It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I see. The problem is that you elements are still placed based on the top/left position, and that is not influenced by the transition. The only thing that comes to mind is to either adjust left/top properties on `:hover` as well, or to use `scale()`.

Comment: Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/36hhyvkg/2/

Comment: I would rather not use the scale. I guess if there is no way to control the origin I'll have to rely on top/left transition. Let's see if someone has some good idea.

Comment: So, if I get it right, your want this result: https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/04b0nmcf/ or this other one: https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/wnvbbswd/ but without transitioning top/left/bottom/right and also without `transform`, right?

Comment: The first fiddle you posted is what I thought could be a solution. But I was wondering if there is some CSS property I'm missing or some smart way to achieve it without modifying top/left/... values.

Comment: Well, the second one does exactly the same (doing the element 1/3 of its size with transition from its center)

Comment: `transform: scale` does the job, you just need to use it properly. Your fiddle where you show how the scale work on the element, not its container, have one big flaw, the resizing sample using width/height is set to 33% (going from 30 to 10) so for the scale to match that is should be .33, not .1 ... updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6gyp3f7k/1/

Answer (score 15):

Well, you can always use transform - scale for that matter:

```css
div {
  background:pink;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  transition:all 1s ease;
}
div:hover{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
        transform: scale(0.1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to use width and height value change.

Comment: the width and the height are for the content of the element, from left to right and top to bottom. You can implement this kind of animation with keyframes, alongside animating the margin left/right/top/bottom and also using another wrapper element to keep the animation oriented. but that a lot of boilerplate code. I believe transform + scale is the best solution- and for browser which does not support this feature (1% of the users), well, they just won't have the animation displayed, thats all.

Comment: Because I am using percentages. **Percentages in Transform refer to the element itself**, not the container. (And I don't want to use javascript for setting the exact scale value).

Answer (score 5):

The best way is using matrix, this allows you to combine transitions and transformations. 
The matrix takes 6 arguments

transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, e, f);

Where

a= scale X axis

b= skewX

c= skewY

d= scale Y axis

e= position X

f= position Y

In this case, I set the scale on the X axis (which is going to alter the width) to the double of the initial width after hover. (the value 2 means initial scale times 2)
The scale on the Y axis is not altered (the value 1 means initial scale times 1, so the height won't change) The rest of the arguments are 0 because you don't need to use them in this case.

```css
.example {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 35%;
  transition: width, height, transform 1s;
}
.example:hover {
  transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using `transform: translate` when animating positions since it's [better for performance](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) and you can then control its origin with `transform-origin`.

And if you want to change the width or height you can similarly use `transform: scale`.

Say you want to double something in size from the center outwards. Then you'd just need to write `transform: scale(2.0)`, since the default value of `transform-origin` is `50% 50%`.

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ydpx284g/

Comment: Could you please elaborate how.

Answer (score 4):

You could change the position at the same time to simulate the effect. But I'm with the others: `transform: scale` is a better approach to this.

```css
div, span {
  width:30%;
  height:30%;
  background:pink;
  transition:all 1s ease;
  position:absolute;
}
div{
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
}
div:hover{
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
}
span{
  bottom:10%;
  right:10%;
}
span:hover{
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
  bottom: 20%;
  right: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

Version with transforms:

```css
div, span {
  width:30%;
  height:30%;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
}
div{
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
}
div:hover{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: scale(0.3);
}
span{
  bottom:10%;
  right:10%;
}
span:hover{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks Jordi. This is the idea I had, but let's see if someone else has some other way. As I said in other comment, **Percentages in Transform refer to the element itself**, not the container, so it's not a solution.

Comment: I've added a new snippet using transforms, @Alvaro

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but this solution is not based on the `transform: scale` and you can manually set the desired width and height of your div on hover even in percentage.

And the percentage is relative to the width of the container.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}

.box{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #000;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover{
  width: 7%;
  height: 10%;
}

.box:nth-child(2){
  left: 20%;
}

.box:nth-child(3){
  top: 20%;
}

.box:nth-child(4){
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #000;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box:hover {
  width: 7%;
  height: 10%;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20%;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20%;
}
.box:nth-child(4) {
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` see if that helps.

```css
.example {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background: pink;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.example:hover {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what are you trying to achieve? using `translate` will change the position of the element based on the width and height of the element itself.

```css
div, span {
  width:30%;
  height:30%;
  background:pink;
  transition:all 1s ease;
  position:absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
*:hover{
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
}
div{
  top:25%;
  left:25%;
}
span{
  top:75%;
  left:75%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: This is amazing, I do not understand the low popularity of your answer ..